# Removing items from the list that are not in the tuple

Tags: python, list

Write and test a Python function leppard to go through the zoo_list and remove any item that is not also in zoo_dictionary. Use the following tuple as the dictionary:

### ( "lion", "tiger", "bear", "chupacabra", "giraffe", "sloth" )

```
n = int(input("Enter the number of animals: "))
zoo_list = []
zoo_dictionary = ( "lion", "tiger", "bear", "chupacabra", "giraffe", "sloth" )
for i in range(n):
    lists = input("Enter the names of each animal: ")
    zoo_list.append(lists)


for i in range(n-1):
    if zoo_list[i] not in zoo_dictionary:
        zoo_list1 = zoo_list.pop(i)
```

### print(zoo_list)

that's my code but when I enter "cat" "dog" "lion" "bear" "monkey" 
my list shows ["dog","lion","bear"]
any reason why? please and thank you :)

Comment: You have solutions below, but the way to get at them is e.g. to inspect the value of `zoo_list` and `zoo_list1` in a debugger. That should have given you a hint what is going on. That said, the "dictionary" is already the wrong type, it should be a set: `zoo = {'dingo', 'mouse', 'hedgehog'}`.

Comment: This kind of problem really lends itself to being solved using list comprehensions (or generator expressions). In this case, the list of elements in `zoo_list` which are not also in `zoo_dictionary` is `[x for x in zoo_list if x not in zoo_dictionary]`. I think the beauty (besids being concise) of this is that it almost reads like Enligsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the first iteration of your second for loop when the value of i is 0,
when you did

```
zoo_list1 = zoo_list.pop(i)
```

the element at index 0 in the list get removed. Now the list becomes

```
["dog", "lion", "bear", "monkey"]
```

Now the loop continues and in the second iteration of the loop, the value of i is 1, and in the new list(formed after first iteration) the element at index 1 is "lion". Thus you are missing the element "dog".

And what you are saying a dictionary is actually a set, not dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in one of the other answers, mutating a list you're trying to iterate over is a recipe for disaster.  Instead, build a new list and then assign that list to `zoo_list`

```
n = int(input("Enter the number of animals: "))
zoo_list = []
zoo_dictionary = ("lion", "tiger", "bear", "chupacabra", "giraffe", "sloth")
for i in range(n):
    zoo_list.append(input("Enter the names of each animal: "))

zoo_list = [animal for animal in zoo_list if animal in zoo_animals]
print(zoo_list)
```

I've remove the unnecessary assignment to the `lists` variable.  I've also removed your erroneous for loop and replaced it with a list comprehension.  If you wanted to use a for loop still, you'd do something like this

```
temp = []
for animal in zoo_list:
    if animal in zoo_dictionary:
        temp.append(animal)
zoo_list = temp
```

You could also use the builtin function [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter).  Replace the list comprehension or the for loop (whichever method you use) with the following.

```
zoo_list = filter(lambda x : x in zoo_animals, zoo_list)
```

and you'll get the same result.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use a while loop here. Here's a the code for Python 2.

```
    n = int(input("Enter the number of animals: "))
    zoo_list = []
    zoo_dictionary = ( "lion", "tiger", "bear", "chupacabra", "giraffe", "sloth" )

    while len(zoo_list) < n:
        item = input("Enter the names of each animal: ")
        zoo_list.append(item)

    print zoo_list, len(zoo_list)
    for i in range(n-1):
        if zoo_list[i] in zoo_dictionary:
            zoo_list.remove(zoo_list[i])

    print zoo_list
```